# Apple lookup JSON data downloads as text file

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a code which looks up the Apple data from the Apple Search API and processes it for displaying it on my site.

If I call the lookup URL in my browser, it downloads the data as a text file.

It still seemed to work fine when I called the code with a cron job.

My site was hosted by a webhosting company.

Now I moved my website to another provider where I have a virtual server.
I installed and enabled Apache, PHP, Curl, Json.
The website shows up, but the Apple lookup doesn't work and I don't know if it is because the text file download, or if I am missing something on the new server.

Can somebody tell me, what the problem might be?
My code is this:

```
    //Call Apple search 
    $cas = curl_init('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=' . $appID . '');
    curl_setopt($cas, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $jsonitunes = curl_exec($cas);
    curl_close($cas);


        //Process Apple search
        $arr = json_decode($jsonitunes,true);


                if ($arr['resultCount'] == '0') {
                //Delete obsolate apps
                mysqli_query($bd, "DELETE FROM appstoimport WHERE app = ".$appID."") or die(mysqli_error());

                } 

                    else {

                        foreach($arr['results'] as $item) {

                        if ($item['kind'] == 'software') {
                        $price  = $item['price'];

                            if ($price > 0) {
                            $free = 0;
                            } else {
                            $free = 1;
                            }


                            $icon = $item['artworkUrl512'];

...

Rest of code
```

Comment: Check whether lookup url is pinging on virtual server or not

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how to do that? I am really a beginner working with servers. I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my server and I use Putty.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to virtual server via putty
2. Once you're in run this command

> ping google.co.in

3. If there is no ping response, contact your virtual server provider as there is no internet connectivity on the server.
4. If there is some response, run curl command

> curl -vvv https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=appId

5. If it is working, then it should work through php also

Comment: Thanks!
It worked. I got the JSON data in putty. The code still doesn't do anything, although it worked before.
So it seems, that something else is wrong.

Comment: What's the output of `$jsonitunes`?

Comment: It's the JSON that Apple gives back if you look up an iOS App ID.